Azure Application Insights Shows Events in Live Metrics But Not Event Tables
I am logging custom events from my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. I can see those events display in Live Metrics shortly after they are sent, but I'm not able to find them in any of the 'events' tables to query later.
I've checked in the 'customEvents' table in Log Analytics, and I've also checked the 'AppEvents' table in my Log Analytics Workspace. It has been more than 24 hours since those events were seen in Live Metrics, which I assume is more than enough time for processing to occur. Is there something I'm missing?
I am running a custom ITelemetryInitializer, but it only operates on request and dependency telemetry:
public class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void InitializeTelemetry(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry dependency)
        {
            // manipulate dependency data
        }

        if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry request)
        {
            // manipulate request data
        }
    }
}

Most of my configuration is accomplished in appsettings.json:
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "redacted",
    "DeveloperMode": false,
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": true,
    "EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule": true,
    "EnablePerformanceCountersCollectionModule": false,
    "EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup": true,
    "InitialSamplingPercentage": 5,
    "SamplingSettings": {
      "MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 5,
      "ExcludedTypes": "Event",
      "IncludedTypes": "Exception;Dependency;Trace;Request"
    }
}

I suspect AdaptiveSampling has something to do with it, but I'm not sure why that would allow me to see it in Live Metrics and then not in the table afterwards.
EDIT:
I was asked to provide my Program.cs file, but for these purposes, my ApplicationInsights registration is all happening in Startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
    {
        Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")
                     .Bind(options);
    });

    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryInitializer>();
}


Can you please share your Program.cs file

@Harshitha I've added the relevant registration sections from my Startup.cs file.

Instead of AddScoped add the TelemetryInitializer as services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryInitializer>();

@Harshitha That is my mistake.  Mine is also registered as a Singleton, I typed it incorrectly when formatting my edit.  I'll update it again.

From what I can tell, the problem here seems to be the Daily Data Cap that we've set for this instrumentation key on the Azure side.  MS documentation indicates that reaching the daily cap should block "all billable data from being ingested", but it seems that "ingested" may be referring only to the underlying tables where this information would be queryable, and not necessarily blocking telemetry from hitting AppInsights altogether.
I'm now using an entirely separate instrumentation key that does not have the same limitations, and I've been able to see my events in both Live Metrics and Log Analytics.

I am able to see the Custom Events in Live Metrics, Transaction Search and Logs in Application Insights with the default and the configuration which you have shared.
Live Metrics:

Transaction Search:

Logs - Application Insights:

and as well as in LogAnalytics - AppEvents Table.

My Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
});

My TelemetryInitializer.cs file:
private readonly TelemetryClient _tc;
if (telemetry is EventTelemetry eventTel)
{
    if (eventTel.Name == "CustomEventName" && eventTel.Properties.ContainsKey("CustProp1"))
    {
        _tc.TrackEvent(eventTel.Name, eventTel.Properties, eventTel.Metrics);
    }   
}

My Controller Class:
With EventTelemetry:
 private readonly TelemetryClient _tc;
 public WeatherForecastController(TelemetryClient tc,ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
 {
    _tc = tc;
     logger = logger;
 }
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
 public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
 { 
     var customEventTel = new EventTelemetry("CustomEventName");
     customEventTel.Properties.Add("CustomProperty", "SamValTest1");
     _tc.TrackEvent(customEventTel);
     ------
 }

Without EventTelemetry:
 _tc.TrackEvent("CustomEventName", new Dictionary<string, string>
 {
    { "CustProp1", "SamValTest1" },
    { "CustProp2", "SamValTest2" }
 });


I suspect AdaptiveSampling has something to do with it,


Adaptive Sampling helps to reduce the telemetry data for the configured properties.
Yes, the issue seems to be with your Adaptive Sampling Configuration.
Remove the "ExcludedTypes": "Event", from appsettings.json file and check once.


I tried removing "ExcludedTypes": "Event", but this doesn't seem to have done anything.  My understanding is that ExcludedTypes specifies telemetry types which should be excluded from sampling, not from having their telemetry sent.  Either way, I am still confused how it is possible to see the events in Live Metrics, which indicates they're being sent, but not be able to query them in any of the tables you showed.

Can you try with my code once.

Have you tried with code in api?

I wound up creating a brand new .NET 8 web api project and hooking in ApplicationInsights in the way that I posted.  I tried sending custom events and saw the same behavior; visible in Live Metrics, but not queryable.  I then tried creating an entirely new instrumentation key, and without changing anything else in the app other than that, I can query those metrics.  This makes me think it's something on the Azure side that is making this possible, but I have no idea what that would be.
